# Maximum height for tagalong

Tags: trailer, children

My daughter is not a very experienced cyclist so on holiday I would like to rent a shared bike.

However, at her size (133cm/26kg) she appears to be in a gap where she is too small for a tandem but may be a bit big for a tagalong

Does anyone know what the maximum size is for riding on a tagalong?

Comment: Tagalongs vary between brands and designs, but she seems a reasonable height given the ages they're typically used for. There's always a follow-me tandem (one brand name) which attaches a whole kid's bike to the back of an adult's. People I know who've used them reckon they're better than tagalongs anyway. This may not be available as you're hiring.

Comment: There are also tandems which allow all sizes of second rider, with the stoker sitting in a recumbent position in front, the rear of the bike a 'normal sit up bike' configuration. (Not available everywhere, alas.) Hase Pino for example, (commercial link, http://www.kinetics-online.co.uk/recumbents/hase/pino/ )